# ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> sys.set_int_max_str_digits(4300)  # Illustrative, this is the default.
> >>> _ = int('2' * 5432)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion: value has 5432 digits.
> ```

Python 3.10.7 introduced this breaking change for type conversion.

Documentation: [Integer string conversion length limitation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation)

Actually I don't understand why

1. this was introduced and
2. where does the default value of 4300 come from? Sounds like an arbitrary number.

Comment: The page you linked to explains the rationale. I suspect the default value is related to the size of some internal array being a multiple of 1024.

Comment: I found this in the CPython source: "Default int base conversion size limitation: [...] Chosen such that this isn't wildly slow on modern hardware and so that everyone's existing deployed numpy test suite passes [...] 4300 decimal digits fits a ~14284 bit number."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See github issue [CVE-2020-10735: Prevent DoS by large int<->str conversions #95778](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95778):

> **Problem**
>
> A Denial Of Service (DoS) issue was identified in CPython
> because we use binary bignum’s for our int implementation. A huge
> integer will always consume a near-quadratic amount of CPU time in
> conversion to or from a base 10 (decimal) string with a large number
> of digits. No efficient algorithm exists to do otherwise.
>
> It is quite common for Python code implementing network protocols and
> data serialization to do int(untrusted_string_or_bytes_value) on input
> to get a numeric value, without having limited the input length or to
> do `log("processing thing id %s", unknowingly_huge_integer)` or any
> similar concept to convert an int to a string without first checking
> its magnitude. (`http`, `json`, `xmlrpc`, `logging`, loading large values into
> integer via linear-time conversions such as hexadecimal stored in
> yaml, or anything computing larger values based on user controlled
> inputs… which then wind up attempting to output as decimal later on).
> All of these can suffer a CPU consuming DoS in the face of untrusted
> data.
>
> Everyone auditing all existing code for this, adding length guards,
> and maintaining that practice everywhere is not feasible nor is it
> what we deem the vast majority of our users want to do.
>
> This issue has been reported to the Python Security Response Team
> multiple times by a few different people since early 2020, most
> recently a few weeks ago while I was in the middle of polishing up the
> PR so it’d be ready before 3.11.0rc2.
>
> **Mitigation**
>
> After discussion on the Python Security Response Team
> mailing list the conclusion was that we needed to limit the size of
> integer to string conversions for non-linear time conversions
> (anything not a power-of-2 base) by default. And offer the ability to
> configure or disable this limit.
>
> The Python Steering Council is aware of this change and accepts it as
> necessary.

Further discussion can be found on the Python Core Developers Discuss thread [Int/str conversions broken in latest Python bugfix releases](https://discuss.python.org/t/int-str-conversions-broken-in-latest-python-bugfix-releases/18889).

I found [this comment](https://discuss.python.org/t/int-str-conversions-broken-in-latest-python-bugfix-releases/18889/2) by Steve Dower to be informative:

> Our apologies for the lack of transparency in the process here. The
> issue was first reported to a number of other security teams, and
> converged in the Python Security Response Team where we agreed that
> the correct fix was to modify the runtime.
>
> The delay between report and fix is entirely our fault. The security
> team is made up of volunteers, our availability isn’t always reliable,
> and there’s nobody “in charge” to coordinate work. We’ve been
> discussing how to improve our processes. However, we did agree that
> the potential for exploitation is high enough that we didn’t want to
> disclose the issue without a fix available and ready for use.
>
> We did work through a number of alternative approaches, implementing
> many of them. The code doing int(gigabyte_long_untrusted_string) could
> be anywhere inside a json.load or HTTP header parser, and can run very
> deep. Parsing libraries are everywhere, and tend to use int
> indiscriminately (though they usually handle ValueError already).
> Expecting every library to add a new argument to every int() call
> would have led to thousands of vulnerabilities being filed, and made
> it impossible for users to ever trust that their systems could not be
> DoS’d.
>
> We agree it’s a heavy hammer to do it in the core, but it’s also the
> only hammer that has a chance of giving users the confidence to keep
> running Python at the boundary of their apps.
>
> Now, I’m personally inclined to agree that int->str conversions should
> do something other than raise. I was outvoted because it would break
> round-tripping, which is a reasonable argument that I accepted. We can
> still improve this over time and make it more usable. However, in most
> cases we saw, rendering an excessively long string isn’t desirable
> either. That should be the opt-in behaviour.
>
> Raising an exception from str may prove to be too much, and could be
> reconsidered, but we don’t see a feasible way to push out updates to
> every user of int, so that will surely remain global.

Answer (score 14):

if you get this error:

```
ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion
```

you can increase the limit by:

```
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
```

Now, you can do bigger calculations.

Link to documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation

Answer (score 2):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation) contains this brief explanation:

> Limiting conversion size offers a practical way to avoid [CVE-2020-10735.](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-10735)

... and later on

> The default [`sys.int_info.default_max_str_digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.int_info.default_max_str_digits) is expected to be reasonable for most applications.

The other answers here and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693104/valueerror-exceeds-the-limit-4300-for-integer-string-conversion/77249010#comment130132514_73693104) already contain more details if you are curious, but I included these passages to make this answer self-contained.

If you need to raise the limit, please understand that Python needs to compile your code before it can be run. If you embed a number which exceeds this limit, you get a syntax error, even if you attempt to raise the limit within your script.

```
# XXX BUGGY, see text
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
bigone = 14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859502445945534690830264252230825334468503526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300192787661119590921642019893809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151557485724245415069595082953311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285836160356370766010471018194295559619894676783744944825537977472684710404753464620804668425906949129331367702898915210475216205696602405803815019351125338243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992458631503028618297455570674983850549458858692699569092721079750930295532116534498720275596023648066549911988183479775356636980742654252786255181841757467289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115735255213347574184946843852332390739414333454776241686251898356948556209921922218427255025425688767179049460165346680498862723279178608578438382796797668145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528502221066118630674427862203919494504712371378696095636437191728746776465757396241389086583264599581339047802759009946576407895126946839835259570982582262052248940772671947826848260147699090264013639443745530506820349625245174939965143142980919065925093722169646151570985838741059788595977297549893016175392846813826868386894277415599185592524595395943104997252468084598727364469584865383673622262609912460805124388439045124413654976278079771569143599770012961608944169486855584840635342207222582848864815845602850601684273945226746767889525213852254995466672782398645659611635488623057745649803559363456817432411251507606947945109659609402522887971089314566913686722874894056010150330861792868092087476091782493858900971490967598526136554978189312978482168299894872265880485756401427047755513237964145152374623436454285844479526586782105114135473573952311342716610213596953623144295248493718711014576540359027993440374200731057853906219838744780847848968332144571386875194350643021845319104848100537061468067491927819119793995206141966342875444064374512371819217999839101591956181467514269123974894090718649423196156794520809514655022523160388193014209376213785595663893778708303906979207734672218256259966150142150306803844773454920260541466592520149744285073251866600213243408819071048633173464965145390579626856100550810665879699816357473638405257145910289706414011097120628043903975951567715770042033786993600723055876317635942187312514712053292819182618612586732157919841484882916447060957527069572209175671167229109816909152801735067127485832228718352093539657251210835791513698820914442100675103346711031412671113699086585163983150197016515116851714376576183515565088490998985998238734552833163550764791853589322618548963213293308985706420467525907091548141654985946163718027098199430992448895757128289059232332609729971208443357326548938239119325974636673058360414281388303203824903758985243744170291327656180937734440307074692112019130203303801976211011004492932151608424448596376698389522868478312355265821314495768572624334418930396864262434107732269780280731891544110104468232527162010526522721116603966655730925471105578537634668206531098965269186205647693125705863566201855810072936065987648611791045334885034611365768675324944166803962657978771855608455296541266540853061434443185867697514566140680070023787765913440171274947042056223053899456131407112700040785473326993908145466464588079727082668306
```

Traceback:

```
  File "/tmp/bigun.py", line 3
    27211166039666557309254711055785376346682065310989652691862056476931257058635662018558100729360659876486117910453348850346113657686753249441668039626579787718556084552965412665408530614344431858676975145661406800700237877659134401712749470420562230538994561314071127000407854733269939081454664645880797270826683063
SyntaxError: Exceeds the limit (4300 digits) for integer string conversion: value has 4302 digits; use sys.set_int_max_str_digits() to increase the limit - Consider hexadecimal for huge integer literals to avoid decimal conversion limits.
```

As demonstrated in several examples in the documentation, the workaround for this is to embed the number as a string, then convert it at run time (so that `sys.set_int_max_str_digits()` actually gets run before Python attempts to parse the big number):

```
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
bigone = int("141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890977772793800081647060016145249192173217214772350141441973568548161361157352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573962413890865832645995813390478027590099465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203496252451749399651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753928468138268683868942774155991855925245953959431049972524680845987273644695848653836736222626099124608051243884390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467678895252138522549954666727823986456596116354886230577456498035593634568174324112515076069479451096596094025228879710893145669136867228748940560101503308617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364542858444795265867821051141354735739523113427166102135969536231442952484937187110145765403590279934403742007310578539062198387447808478489683321445713868751943506430218453191048481005370614680674919278191197939952061419663428754440643745123718192179998391015919561814675142691239748940907186494231961567945208095146550225231603881930142093762137855956638937787083039069792077346722182562599661501421503068038447734549202605414665925201497442850732518666002132434088190710486331734649651453905796268561005508106658796998163574736384052571459102897064140110971206280439039759515677157700420337869936007230558763176359421873125147120532928191826186125867321579198414848829164470609575270695722091756711672291098169091528017350671274858322287183520935396572512108357915136988209144421006751033467110314126711136990865851639831501970165151168517143765761835155650884909989859982387345528331635507647918535893226185489632132933089857064204675259070915481416549859461637180270981994309924488957571282890592323326097299712084433573265489382391193259746366730583604142813883032038249037589852437441702913276561809377344403070746921120191302033038019762110110044929321516084244485963766983895228684783123552658213144957685726243344189303968642624341077322697802807318915441101044682325271620105265227211166039666557309254711055785376346682065310989652691862056476931257058635662018558100729360659876486117910453348850346113657686753249441668039626579787718556084552965412665408530614344431858676975145661406800700237877659134401712749470420562230538994561314071127000407854733269939081454664645880797270826683063")
```

You can also override this setting via an environment variable; at the shell prompt, this would look like

```bash
PYTHONINTMAXSTRDIGITS=0 python yourscript.py
```

or with the `-X` option

```bash
python -X int_max_str_digits yourscript.py
```