# Using a literal number with 35660 digits raises SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

I'm copying and pasting 10000! from the web, and this number has 35660 digits, but I'm getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion: value has 35660 digits; use sys.set_int_max_str_digits() to increase the limit - Consider hexadecimal for huge integer literals to avoid decimal conversion limits.

I wrote the following because it's supposed to eliminate the the maximum value allowed to use:

```
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
```

But I still get the error.

I went on [this site](https://coolconversion.com/math/factorial/_10000_) and copied the 10000! value and pasted it into my IDE.

```
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)

x = 28462596809170545189064132121198688901480514017027992307941799942744113400037644437729907867577847758158840621423175288300423399401535187390524211613827161748198241998275924182892597878981242531205946599625986706560161572036032397926328736717055741975962099479720346153698119897092611277500484198845410475544642442136573303076703628825803548967461117097369578603670191071512730587281041158640561281165385325968425825995584688146430425589836649317059251717204276597407446133400054194052462303436869154059404066227828248371512038322178644627183822923899638992827221879702459387693803094627332292570555459690027875282242544348021127559019169425429028916907219097083690539873747452483372899521802363282741217040268086769210451555840567172555372015852132829034279989818449313610640381489304499621599999359670892980190336998484404665419236258424947163178961192041233108268651071354516845540936033009607210346944377982349430780626069422302681885227592057029230843126188497606560742586279448827155956831533440534425446648416894580425709461673613187605234982286326452921529423479870603344290737158688499178932580691483168854251956006172372636323974420786924642956012306288720122652952964091508301336630982733806353972901506581822574295475894399765113865541208125788683704239208764484761569001264889271590706306409661628038784044485191643790807186112370622133415415065991843875961023926713276546986163657706626438638029848051952769536195259240930908614471907390768585755934786981720734372093104825475628567777694081564074962275254993384112809289637516990219870492405617531786346939798024619737079041868329931016554150742308393176878366923694849025999607729684293977427536263119825416681531891763234839190821000147178932184227805135181734921901146246875769835373441456013122615221391178759688367364087207937002992038279198038702372078039140312368997608152840306051116709484722224870389199993442071395836983063962232079115624044250808919914319837120445598344047556759489212101498152454543594285414390843564419984224855478532163624030098442855331829253154206551237079705816393460296247697010388742206441536626733715428700789122749340684336442889847100840641600093623935261248037975293343928764398316390312776450722479267851700826669598389526150759007349215197592659192708873202594066382118801988854748266048342256457705743973122259700671936061763513579529821794290797705327283267501488024443528681645026165662837546519006171873442260438919298506071515390031106684727360135816706437861756757439184376479658136100599638689552334648781746143243573224864326798481981458432703035895508420534788493364582482592033288089025782388233265770205248970937047210214248413342465268206806732314214483854074182139621846870108359582946965235632764870475718351616879235068366271743711915723361143070121120767608697851559721846485985918643641716850899625516820910793570231118518174775010804622585521314764897490660752877082897667514951009682329689732000622392888056658036140311285465929084078033974900664953205873164948093883816198658850827382468034897864757116679890423568018303504133875731972630897909435710687797301633918087868474943633533893373586906405848417828065196275826434429258058422212947649402948622670761832988229004072390403733168207417413251656688443079339447019208905620788387585342512820957359307018197708340163817638278562539516825426644614941044711579533262372815468794080423718587423026200264221822694188626212107297776657401018376182280136857586442185863011539843712299107010094061929413223202773193959467006713695377097897778118288242442920864816134179562017471831609687661043140497958198236445807368209404022211181530051433387076607063149616107771117448059552764348333385744040212757031851527298377435921878558552795591028664457917362007221858143309977294778923720717942857756271300923982397921957581197264742642878266682353915687857271620146192244266266708400765665625807109474398740110772811669918806268726626565583345665007890309050656074633078027158530817691223772813510584527326591626219647620571434880215630815259005343721141000303039242866457207328473481712034168186328968865048287367933398443971236735084527340196309427697652684170174990756947982757825835229994315633322107439131550124459005324702680312912392297979030417587823398622373535054642646913502503951009239286585108682088070662734733200354995720397086488066040929854607006339409885836349865466136727880748764700702458790118046518296111277090609016152022111461543158317669957060974618085359390400067892878548827850938637353703904049412684618991272871562655001270833039950257879931705431882752659225814948950746639976007316927310831735883056612614782997663188070063044632429112260691931278881566221591523270457695867512821990938942686601963904489718918597472925310322480210543841044325828472830584297804162405108110326914001900568784396341502696521048920272140232160234898588827371428695339681755106287470907473718188014223487248498558198439094651708364368994306189650243288353279667190184527620551085707626204244509623323204744707831190434499351442625501701771017379551124746159471731862701565571266295855125077711738338208419705893367323724453280456537178514960308802580284067847809414641838659226652806867978843250660537943046250287105104929347267471267499892634627358167146935060495110340755404658170393481046758485625967767959768299409334026387269378365320912287718077451152622642548771835461108886360843272806227776643097283879056728618036048633464893371439415250259459652501520959536157977135595794965729775650902694428088479761276664847003619648906043761934694270444070215317943583831051404915462608728486678750541674146731648999356381312866931427616863537305634586626957894568275065810235950814888778955073939365341937365700848318504475682215444067599203138077073539978036339267334549549296668759922530893898086430606532961793164029612492673080638031873912596151131890359351266480818568366770286537742390746582390910955517179770580797789289752490230737801753142680363914244720257728891784950078117889336629750436804214668197824272980697579391742229456683185815676816288797870624531246651727622758295493421483658868919299587402095696000243560305289829866386892076992834030549710266514322306125231915131843876903823706205399206933943716880466429711476743564486375026847698148853105354063328845062012173302630676481322931561043551941761050712449024873277273112091945865137493190965162497691657553812198566432207978666300398938660238607357858114394715872800893374165033792965832618436073133327526023605115524227228447251463863269369763762510196714380125691227784428426999440829152215904694437282498658085205186576292992775508833128672638418713277780874446643875352644733562441139447628780974650683952982108174967958836452273344694873793471790710064978236466016680572034297929207446822322848665839522211446859572858403863377278030227591530497865873919513650246274195899088374387331594287372029770620207120213038572175933211162413330422773742416353553587977065309647685886077301432778290328894795818404378858567772932094476778669357537460048142376741194182671636870481056911156215614357516290527351224350080604653668917458196549482608612260750293062761478813268955280736149022525819682815051033318132129659664958159030421238775645990973296728066683849166257949747922905361845563741034791430771561168650484292490281102992529678735298767829269040788778480262479222750735948405817439086251877946890045942060168605142772244486272469911146200149880662723538837809380628544384763053235070132028029488392008132135446450056134987017834271106158177289819290656498688081045562233703067254251277277330283498433595772575956224703707793387146593033088629699440318332665797514676502717346298883777397848218700718026741265997158728035440478432478674907127921672898523588486943546692255101337606377915164597254257116968477339951158998349081888281263984400505546210066988792614558214565319696909827253934515760408613476258778165867294410775358824162315779082538054746933540582469717674324523451498483027170396543887737637358191736582454273347490424262946011299881916563713847111849156915054768140411749801454265712394204425441028075806001388198650613759288539038922644322947990286482840099598675963580999112695367601527173086852756572147583507122298296529564917835071750835741362282545055620270969417476799259229774888627411314587676147531456895328093117052696486410187407673296986649236437382565475022816471926815559883196629848307776666840622314315884384910519058281816740764463033300119710293036455866594651869074475250837841987622990415911793682799760654186088721626654886492344391030923256910633775969739051781122764668486791736049404393703339351900609387268397299246478483727274770977466693599784857120156789000241947269220974984127323147401549980920381459821416481176357147801554231599667838534854486406936410556913531335231184053581348940938191821898694825383960989942822027599339635206217705343572073396250574216769465101608495601439303244304271576099527308684609204422226103154229984444802110098161333824827375218998738205315164927134498105950159974800571591912202154487748750103473246190633941303030892399411985006225902184164409988173214324422108554248620896250260604398180189026317781146617454999771440665232863846363847001655618153861098188111181734191305505024860345856755585637511729774299329074944236579668332700918367338977347901759248885660379952771540569083017311723894140326159612292912225191095948743805673381278538616491842786938417556898047100859868372033615175158097022566275200160956192229925401759878522038545913771783976389811198485803291048751666921195104514896677761598249468727420663437593207852618922687285527671324883267794152912839165407968344190239094803676688707838011367042753971396201424784935196735301444404037823526674437556740883025225745273806209980451233188102729012042997989005423126217968135237758041162511459175993279134176507292826762236897291960528289675223521425234217247841869317397460411877634604625637135309801590617736758715336803958559054827361876112151384673432884325090045645358186681905108731791346215730339540580987172013844377099279532797675531099381365840403556795731894141976511436325526270639743146526348120032720096755667701926242585057770617893798231096986788448546659527327061670308918277206432551919393673591346037757083193180845929565158875244597601729455720505595085929175506510115665075521635142318153548176884196032085050871496270494017684183980582594038182593986461260275954247433376226256287153916069025098985070798660621732200163593938611475394561406635675718526617031471453516753007499213865207768523824884600623735896608054951652406480547295869918694358811197833680141488078321213457152360124065922208508912956907835370576734671667863780908
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But depending on exactly what they did may indicate the cause of the problem. E.g. if the int literal occurs in a script, then the compiler may attempt to parse int literals before it executes a preceding `sys` function call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693104/valueerror-exceeds-the-limit-4300-for-integer-string-conversion

Comment: @tripleee You can now copy paste what I almost have in my IDE (the number I'm using has 35660 digits and stackoverflow only allows 30000 digits max per post, so I reduced the number to fit in the post)

Comment: IMO https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation fails to inform that this also affects integer literals and that `SyntaxError` is raised instead of `ValueError` in that case.

Comment: It's probably a difference between Python versions. The duplicate explains the rationale and now also has an answer by yours truly which explains in more detail why you need to work around with a string or etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the number from string to integer by doing

```py
huge_number = int("2846259680917054518906413212119868...")  # insert the whole number here
```

Using `int()` bypasses the syntax check which is performed before the script can be compiled and run. The syntax error happens when Python tries to parse the number. Running `sys.set_int_max_str_digits()` can obviously only happen after this. But putting the number in a string allows the syntax check to pass, and thus for `sys.set_int_max_str_digits()` to be run before the number is parsed by Python.

You have to set the new limit with the maximum number of digits you need, or just set it to 0 to remove it completely.

The final piece of code consists of:

```py
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)

huge_number = int("2846259680917054518906413212119868...")  # insert the whole number here
```

---

Further explanations on why it helps to put the number as a string were contributed by @tripleee.

Comment: As per the docs, the limit also applies to `int(…)` and 0 is explicitly mentioned to disable the limit.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the 0 to disable the limit. On the other hand, I tried to put the number inside the int(...) or assign it directly to a variable and got the error even with the disabled limit. IDK how this type of conversion works under the hood so by just trial and error this seemed a fine solution to me for this oddly specific problem.

Comment: @DomizianoScarcelli (Please feel free to edit your answer to include my explanation.)

Comment: @DomizianoScarcelli You didn't remove the incorrect assertion that you shouldn't set the limit to zero.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the clear explanation, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a script like this:

```
import sys

sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)

bignumber = 284... # big number
```

The `set_int_max_str_digits` will not prevent the error, because the parser will attempt to parse the int literal before the `set_int_max_str_digits` call is executed.

Instead, you can set the limit before Python starts, using a command-line flag.

E.g.

`python3 -X int_max_str_digits=0 myscript.py`

Then the int can successfully be parsed.

You could also use an environment variable.
See [Configuring the limit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#configuring-the-limit) in the docs.

Comment: in my ide I wrote:  import os   os.environ["PYTHONINTMAXSTRDIGITS"] = "0"  is this correct?

Comment: @Pinteco Setting the limit inside a script is too late to apply to int literals in the same script.

Comment: ok I got it now, but I'm having to use the CMD prompt to run it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int-max-str-digits) CPython has a global limit for converting str to int, to mitigate against denial of service attacks. The flaw was discovered in 2020 and is described here [CVE-2020-10735](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-10735).

This was introduced to Python 3.11, and eventually got back-ported to security updates of python 3.7,.., 3.10 (thank you @mkrieger1)

The default limit is 4300 digits. You can check that value in `sys.int_info.default_max_str_digits`. The lowest limit that can be configured is 640 digits as provided in `sys.int_info.str_digits_check_threshold`.

```
import sys
assert sys.int_info.default_max_str_digits == 4300, sys.int_info
assert sys.int_info.str_digits_check_threshold == 640, sys.int_info
```

If the string you are trying to covert to int exceeds the default, you should use `sys.set_int_max_str_digits(max_digits)` as described in the error message, before running `huge_number = int(huge_number_string)`.

The documentation recommends using a python version agnostic at the entry point of the application as in:

```
import sys
if hasattr(sys, "set_int_max_str_digits"):
    upper_bound = 68000
    lower_bound = 4004
    current_limit = sys.get_int_max_str_digits()
    if current_limit == 0 or current_limit > upper_bound:
        sys.set_int_max_str_digits(upper_bound)
    elif current_limit < lower_bound:
        sys.set_int_max_str_digits(lower_bound)
```

The documentation states that using the value 0 will disable the limitation. However setting the limits should run before the python parser, and setting it in script might be too late.

Maybe the best way to control this limit is to use the environment variable `PYTHONINTMAXSTRDIGITS`.

`PYTHONINTMAXSTRDIGITS=0` should disable the limitation as in:

```
PYTHONINTMAXSTRDIGITS=0 python3 myscript.py
```

or using -X arguments:

```
python3 -X int_max_str_digits=0 myscript.py
```

Comment: Thank you @mkrieger1. I have incorporated your comment in the answer!

Answer (score -1):

This type of methods usually used in huge no of data.it is used to increase the limit
if n no of test running in program and  you are trying to convert a int to string that time this sys.set_int_max_str_digits(#"enter the limit") is used.

example:
Input: num1 = "11", num2 = "123" #string
Output: 134 #int

Answer (score -2):

You can do this, as hex is unlimited

```
import math
f = math.factorial(10000)
hex(f)  # gives the result in hex
```